# Links inside Generated Table Not Running JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery script that hides a div when a link with an ID of 'hide' is clicked.

I generate a table using a viz language (similar to Google Viz) with links inside of it with this ID. It fails to run the JQuery, although it executes another JS script (non-JQuery). I assumed this was because the table takes some time to load, but I've set my JQuery to run only after the DOM has loaded.

Any assistance would be very helpful!

My JQuery below:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('#hide').click(function(){
    $("#splash").hide(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on("click","#hide",function(){..` try this instead

Comment: (1) Use event delegation instead of directly binding the event on the element. (2) Bad idea to use same `id` on multiple elements. (3) Use classes if functionality is repeatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your links are generated through viz language, To take a not IDs must be unique for all the links but anyways you can use classes instead of IDs. I guest your link ID will be repeating.

You should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here.

```
$(document.body).on('click','#hide',function(){
    $("#splash").hide(500);
});
```

But it's recommended to use classes instead of repeating IDs your code should be like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.hide',function(){   // class implementation
    $("#splash").hide(500);
});
```

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.